# Symfony 2.2 upload files

Tags: symfony, file-upload

It's been a while since I uploaded files with Symfony2 and it seems that everything has changed, follow the guide in [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) but is outdated and dont work.

when i try to bind the form a get a error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Entity\Portada::setFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, string given, ...
```

this is my controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/upload", name="documento_upload")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template()
 */
public function uploadAction(Request $request)
{
    $portada = new Portada();
    $form = $this->buildUploadForm($portada);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $portada->upload();
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Hay un error en el formulario");

    }

    //...
}
```

my entity

```
<?php

namespace MyName\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Portada
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    public $path;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->path
        );

        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/'. $this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'uploads/portada';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I forget add enctype to my form after added work perfectly

```
<form action="{{ path('documento_upload') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(upload_form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(upload_form) }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without form builder?

Comment: @Gigala it's possible but i dont try. check `$this->getRequest()->files` that return a FileBag and you can check how to move withut use forms

Comment: If i do it like `<input type="file" name="file">` it is not inside `$this->getRequest()->files`. Instead it is in the Post-Variables of the request and its not the file its just the file name. So i guess im forced to use the FormBuilder