# How can I add images to a custom Entity in Sylius?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I've a custom entity (campaign) that must be able to manage an image file, so I can upload one via the administrator.I've done it trying to follow Taxon entity as an example. The problem is that when trying to create a new campaign through the administration form it returns the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Campaign::setFile() must be an instance of SplFileInfo, string given, called in /NetBeansProjects/tiendacoleman/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 350 and defined in /NetBeansProjects/tiendacoleman/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Entity/Campaign.php line 100

```
namespace Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\ImageInterface;
use SplFileInfo;
use DateTime;

class Campaign implements ImageInterface
{
     protected $id;
     protected $campaign;
     protected $link;
     protected $isActive;
     protected $campaignOrder;

    /**
     * @var SplFileInfo
     */
    protected $file;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCampaign()
    {
        return $this->campaign;
    }

    public function setCampaign($campaign)
    {
        $this->campaign = $campaign;
    }

    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->link;
    }

    public function setLink($link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    public function getCampaignOrder()
    {
        return $this->campaignOrder;
    }

    public function setCampaignOrder($campaignOrder)
    {
        $this->campaignOrder = $campaignOrder;
    }

    public function hasFile()
    {
        return null !== $this->file;
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile(SplFileInfo $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function hasPath()
    {
        return null !== $this->path;
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(DateTime $createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTime $updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }
}
```

This is the code of the form:

```
namespace Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CampaignType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('campaign', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'sylius.form.campaign.name'
            ))
            ->add('link', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'sylius.form.campaign.link'
            ))
            ->add('isActive', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => 'sylius.form.campaign.active'
            ))
            ->add('file','file',array(
                'label' => 'sylius.form.campaign.file'
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sylius_campaign';
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error as you. I have fixed it following this answer:
[Symfony 2.2 upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150875/symfony-2-2-upload-files)

You have to add "{{ form_enctype(upload_form) }}" to your form tag in the twig template. Replace 'upload_form' with your form variable.

Comment: is someone can do it on 0.18 ? look for the event who triggered the upload mechanism